# Adding icon dynamically if a condition is true

Tags: flutter, if-statement, gesturedetector

I'm trying to add an icon inside my app only if a condition is True, also I want it to be added dynamically, Here's a pseudo-code which I am trying to work in:

```
subtitle: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        child: HebrewText(helpRequest.description),
        //alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, left: 8),
      ),
      Spacer(),
      GestureDetector(
        onTap: ()=>{
          if(helpRequest.handler_id != null) {
                  _launchCaller(),
          },
        } ,
          child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Icon(
                Icons.call,
                size: 20.0,
                color: BasicColor.clr,
              )),
        ),

    ],
  ),
```

I want the gestureDetector to be add to this row only if a condition is true,
Tries to add if condition before the GestureDetector() but it didn't work, is there any simple way to make it?

As you see in my code I put the if condition inside the OnTap, I want to make it on the GestureDetector

Comment: Which condition it depends on ?

Comment: I want to make it depends on if condition (The same condition that found in the OnTap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
null != helpRequest.handler_id ? GestureDetector(
  onTap: _launchCaller ,
  child: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
    child: Icon(
      Icons.call,
      size: 20.0,
      color: BasicColor.clr,),
  ),
) : SizedBox(),
```